# How to release memory handled by numpy

Tags: python, numpy, memory

```
# encoding: utf-8

import sys
import commands
import time
import gc

import numpy

process=sys.argv[0]

def get_use_memory():
    global process
    return commands.getstatusoutput('ps aux | grep "{0}" | grep -v "grep"'.format(process))

def normalize_feature(node, delete_list):
    print 'normalize_feature_step1', get_use_memory()
    normal_features = []
    for i in range(0, node.shape[0]):
        feature_numpy = node[i, :]

        feature_numpy_d = numpy.delete(feature_numpy, delete_list, axis=0)
        normal_features.append(feature_numpy_d)
        del feature_numpy
        del feature_numpy_d

    print 'normalize_feature_step2', get_use_memory()
    np_normal_features = numpy.array(normal_features)
    print sys.getsizeof(np_normal_features) / float(1024) / float(1024)
    print 'normalize_feature_step3', get_use_memory()
    del normal_features
    gc.collect()
    print 'normalize_feature_step4', get_use_memory()
    return np_normal_features

#gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_STATS|gc.DEBUG_LEAK)

rows=1024
columns=10240
a = []
for i in range(0, rows):
    b = []
    for j in range(0, columns):
        b.append(float(i) * j)
    a.append(b)
    del b

print get_use_memory()

node_1 = numpy.array(a)
print sys.getsizeof(node_1) / float(1024) / float(1024)
print get_use_memory()
del a
gc.collect()
print get_use_memory()

node_2 = normalize_feature(node_1, [0, 100, 1000])
print sys.getsizeof(node_2) / float(1024) / float(1024)
print get_use_memory()

del node_1
del node_2
gc.collect()
print get_use_memory()
```

output:

```
(0, 'wangye    5319 96.5  1.0 581036 360528 pts/28  S+   11:23   0:03 python test.py')
80.0001068115
(0, 'wangye    5319  106  1.3 662964 442456 pts/28  S+   11:23   0:04 python test.py')
(0, 'wangye    5319  112  0.2 316812 98072 pts/28   S+   11:23   0:04 python test.py')
normalize_feature_step1 (0, 'wangye    5319  112  0.2 316812 98072 pts/28   S+   11:23   0:04 python test.py')
normalize_feature_step2 (0, 'wangye    5319  115  0.5 398372 179704 pts/28  S+   11:23   0:04 python test.py')
79.9766693115
normalize_feature_step3 (0, 'wangye    5319  116  0.7 480272 261596 pts/28  S+   11:23   0:04 python test.py')
normalize_feature_step4 (0, 'wangye    5319  116  0.5 398688 180148 pts/28  S+   11:23   0:04 python test.py')
79.9766693115
(0, 'wangye    5319  116  0.5 398688 180148 pts/28  S+   11:23   0:04 python test.py')
(0, 'wangye    5319  117  0.0 234864 16324 pts/28   S+   11:23   0:04 python test.py')
```

Release 80M memory between normalize_feature_step3 and normalize_feature_step4. Because del normal_features release its items which is numpy.ndarray. And the final memory is just 16M.

But when I change the line 38 and 39 of the code to make:
rows=10240
columns=1024

output:

```
(0, 'wangye    5400 99.5  1.1 604944 385888 pts/28  S+   11:25   0:03 python test.py')
80.0001068115
(0, 'wangye    5400  109  1.4 686872 467892 pts/28  S+   11:25   0:04 python test.py')
(0, 'wangye    5400  116  0.2 317024 98176 pts/28   S+   11:25   0:04 python test.py')
normalize_feature_step1 (0, 'wangye    5400  116  0.2 317024 98176 pts/28   S+   11:25   0:04 python test.py')
normalize_feature_step2 (0, 'wangye    5400  100  0.5 399592 180852 pts/28  S+   11:25   0:05 python test.py')
79.7657318115
normalize_feature_step3 (0, 'wangye    5400  101  0.8 481276 262576 pts/28  S+   11:25   0:05 python test.py')
normalize_feature_step4 (0, 'wangye    5400  101  0.7 480444 261904 pts/28  S+   11:25   0:05 python test.py')
79.7657318115
(0, 'wangye    5400  101  0.7 480444 261904 pts/28  S+   11:25   0:05 python test.py')
(0, 'wangye    5400  101  0.2 316836 98296 pts/28   S+   11:25   0:05 python test.py')
```

Memory does not have any change between normalize_feature_step3 and normalize_feature_step4. And the final memory is 98M.

So I think maybe the numpy handle some memory. And I want to know how to release the memory.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Call `gc.collect()` doesn't mean the memory will be recycled. It just tells gc to recycle and whether to do or not is decided by itself, so you can't directly make gc to recycle. This is not a problem about numpy but is a general problem about every language who has gc.

Comment: What does call gc.collect() mean?

Comment: I know. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick mistake you are making:

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> b = []
>>> b.append(a)
>>> b[0] is a
True
```

Adding an element to a list does not *copy* that element, it just adds a pointer to that element to the list (`is` keyword checks for identity matches).

So, when you do `del a` after adding `a` to the list, you are not freeing the memory of `a`, you are just removing the naming reference from `a`. This is, variable with name `a` will cease to exist, but its content will still live in memory, pointed by `b[0]`.

In short, `del` statement in python is not equivalent to `free` in C/C++. If memory is your concern, you should not be using python at all or you should be more careful with your code, but relying on `del` is not an option. `del` should not be used for these purposes.

As an example, when you do simple addition of numpy arrays temporary arrays of the same size are created on the fly to store intermediate values, thus consuming more memory than probably needed.

This this, numpy and in general python are languages/libraries for fast prototyping. If you need full control of the resources being used, you should fall back to C/C++ (or other compiled language). Any interpreted language will *automagically* free the memory then the storage stops being pointed, but it will not be instant, and you cannot rely on that.